# Failure when trying to write/update some features in FME

Tags: file-geodatabase, fme-form

By means of FME 2021, I am trying to update one column in a Point feature class inside FileGDB (FME: writer). Updates are comming from another feature class (FME: reader). I dont have unique ID but I do have x and y coordinates which are unique and match between reader and writer. Even though coordinates are identical in reader and writer, ONLY for some features is not working and pops-up:

> No rows matched UPDATE query to table/feature class 'points' where x =
> 95330918.98604 AND y = 9535458.351159

Let's say for 50 features it is working but for some reasons fails in 3 or 4 features!
settings I used:

- Feature opeation: update
- Match columns: x,y

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I would suspect rounding errors with floating point numbers. Try to round the coordinates for example into full millimetres.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot..... I have to add something. Rounding coordinates is the first thing that I tried but in GIS, and it didnt work because in GIS I think it only lets it display that way but does not remove millimeter values. Now I tried it via "AttributeRounder" inside FME and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: Floating point equivalence is a general IT issue. Some values *can't* be represented. You can do bound-box tests or integer conversion (which is what FGDB uses, so it should work fine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparisons of floating point numbers with high precision are uncertain because of rounding errors. For example it in not possible to store decimal number `95330918.98604` accurately as double precision floating point number but it converts into value, that is  `95330918.98603999614715576171875` when converted back to decimal (result calculated with https://www.exploringbinary.com/floating-point-converter/).

Usually GIS data allows to reduce the accuracy. You will probably find the sama point even with a procision of one millimetre `95330918.986`.